# Email schemas self test looks like a normal message

Tags: google-schemas

I'm tring my schema email.
The json-ld content is just copied from the google example.

I'm sending from my gmail address to my gmail address a custom HTML with json-ld script tag using SMTP connection.

The received email has a valid content, I have validated it using the schema validation tool (https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/), but the message in gmail is shown as a normal message without any special decoration.

What I'm missing?

This is the message:

```
Return-Path: <....@gmail.com>
Received: from .......
To: ....@gmail.com
From: .... <.....@gmail.com>
Subject: test
Message-ID: <.......@gmail.com>
Date: Wed, 14 Apr 2021 10:13:36 +0200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/78.9.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="------------C711D6157D722F58A7A70245"
Content-Language: it

--------------C711D6157D722F58A7A70245
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-15; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

test


--------------C711D6157D722F58A7A70245
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-15
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>
      <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "jobTitle": "Graduate research assistant",
  "affiliation": "University of Dreams",
  "additionalName": "Johnny",
  "url": "http://www.example.com",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "1234 Peach Drive",
    "addressLocality": "Wonderland",
    "addressRegion": "Georgia"
  }
}
</script></p>
  </body>
</html>

--------------C711D6157D722F58A7A70245--
```

Comment: so six months have passed - what happened?

Comment: so far ... nothing

Comment: I'm also having trouble getting them to show up, although the markup used is valid and complete (according to their validation tool), and I've tried using two different accounts (one @gmail.com, one Gsuite).